# Can I make DropDownListFor width the same like TextBoxFor width with Bootstrap class?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, width, dropdownlistfor, html.textboxfor

I have NewCustomer View:

```
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-right">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.GenderId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Customer.GenderId,new SelectList(Model.Genders,"Id", "GenderType"),"-=Select Title=-")
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-right">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Customer.Name)
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Can I align the width dropdownlist and textbox with boostrap class ?

[DropDownList is too narrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVG01.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed code:

```
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.GenderId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">   

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Customer.GenderId, new SelectList(Model.Genders, "Id", "GenderType"), "Select Title", new { @class = "form-control " })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.GenderId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```